# Why can't webmin can't open files in directories that are not world executable?

Tags: perl, file-io, permissions, webmin

I'm using an open source Perl package named "webmin" on several servers. It's mostly Perl on the inside.

I found a weird behavior on a new 64-bit server: files were getting created empty.

I've traced it down to a "Permission Denied" error in Perl's builtin function `open`
which is pretty unusual, since the application is running as root.
I had perl output the $< and $> variables, and they both claim I'm user 0

This bug seems to affect files in directories where the *directory* is not world executable (`chmod o-x $DIR`) ... and it only happens deep inside of webmin, I can't reproduce it on its own.

Does this sound even remotely familiar to anyone?

Comment: You might invoke webmin as root, but it may drop privileges (e.g., by switching to a "webmin" user). You should check which userid the process runs as.

Comment: Are the permissions exactly the same for all servers? Is the Apache setup exactly the same? (Or whatever server software you use.) This sounds like a problem with the server setup or the software. You might try the Webmin wiki: http://doxfer.com/Webmin/WebHome

Answer (score 2):

ACLs on the directory?

SELinux turned on?

The fact that you're getting a "permission denied" error on a directory that doesn't have the execute bit is not surprising - on directories, the execute bit controls accessing the contents of the directory - the question is why the execute bit isn't set.

Check if any umask setting is applying to the process.

Comment: no acls on the directory. not SELinux.

I should only be affected by the *user* execute bit, if I'm the directory owner (I am). And this works just fine on a 32 bit server

Answer (score 2):

> I've traced it down to a "Permission Denied" error
>   *[....]* *[w]*hich is pretty unusual, since the
>   application is running as root.

Are you sure you're running as `root` at the time of the failed `open()`?

webmin's documentation boasts the ability to exec arbitrary commands as *other users*, and a quick grep of the source code shows a number of instances of a function named `switch_to_unix_user()`...

Comment: I had perl output the $< and $> variables, and they both claim I'm user 0

Answer (score 1):

in Unix permissions, you need execute permission on a directory to access anything inside it (you don't need read permission, that's for listing the directory; you only need execute permission to access the contents). so something is accessing the file under a user that is considered "other", and it doesn't have permission

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, and the cause seems to be the length of the path for the file/dir you try to open/write.
In my case i was trying to open a folder which exist and have 777 as permission, but still the system fail saying the dir do not exist.
Did some testing and opening another folder at the same level but with a shorter name was succesfull